# Calculation of orig, norm attributes of NormContinous in PMML

Tags: c#, math, pmml

### Overview

I am currently working on a normalization PMML-Model executor in c#.

These PMML normalization models look like this:

```
 <TransformationDictionary>
    <DerivedField displayName="BU01" name="BU01*" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
      <Extension name="summary" extender="KNIME" value="Min/Max (0.0, 1) normalization on 17 column(s)"/>
      <NormContinuous field="BU01">
        <LinearNorm orig="0.0" norm="-0.6148417019560395"/>
        <LinearNorm orig="1.0" norm="-0.6140350877192982"/>
      </NormContinuous>
    </DerivedField>
(...)
```

I do know how min-max normalization in theory works using

`z_i = (x_i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))`

to normalize a dataset into the range of 0-1 and obviously it's not hard to reverse this equation.

### Problem

So to execute the normlization and denormalization I somehow have to translate this orig, norm values into min, max values. But I just can't figure out how these orig/norm values are being calculated and how they relate to min/max.

### Question

So I'm asking if some does know an equation to transform orig/norm to min/max and back. Or is someone able to explain how to directly use orig/norm values to normalize/denormalize my fields?

### Further Explanation

EDIT: It loks like as if I did not state clearly what the problem exactly is so here is another approach:

I try to get an **attribut** of a dataset **normalized** into the **range from 0-1** using [Min-Max normalization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) (aka `Feature Scaling`). Using the Data Analysis tool Knime I can do this and **export my "scaling"** as a PMML Model. (Example of this is the XML provided above)

With these normalized attributes I train my MLP Model. Now if I export my MLP Model as PMML I have to put normalized values in and get normalized output out when caluclating a prediction. (Computing the MLP Network already works)

In a deployed scenario where Knime can't do this normalization for me I want to use my normalization Model. As already described I do know the theory behing `Feature Scaling` and can easily compute de-/normalization **if I am provided with min and max** of my attribute. The problem is that PMML has another let's say "notation" for saving this min-max information which is somehow inside the `orig` and `norm` value.

So what I am ultimately looking for is a way to convert orig/norm to min/max or how min/max information is "encoded" into orig/norm values.

### Extra Info

[Why this "encoding" is done in the first place seems to be because computation speed reasons (which is not important in my scenario) and to easier encode min/max normlization info for ranges other than 0-1.]

### Example #1

To give an example:
Let's say I want to normalize the array of [0, 1, 2, 4, 8] into the range of 0-1. Clearly the answer is [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1] as computed by `Feature Scaling` with min = 0, max = 8. Easy. But now if I look at the PMML normalization Model:

```
<TransformationDictionary>
  <DerivedField displayName="column1" name="column1*" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
    <Extension name="summary" extender="KNIME" value="Min/Max (0.0, 1) normalization on 1 column(s)"/>
    <NormContinuous field="column1">
      <LinearNorm orig="0.0" norm="0.0"/>
      <LinearNorm orig="1.0" norm="0.125"/>
    </NormContinuous>
  </DerivedField>
</TransformationDictionary>
```

### Example #2

[1, 2, 4, 8] -> [0, 0.333, 0.667, 1]
With:

```
<TransformationDictionary>
  <DerivedField displayName="column1" name="column1*" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
    <Extension name="summary" extender="KNIME" value="Min/Max (0.0, 1) normalization on 1 column(s)"/>
    <NormContinuous field="column1">
      <LinearNorm orig="0.0" norm="-0.3333333333333333"/>
      <LinearNorm orig="1.0" norm="0.0"/>
    </NormContinuous>
  </DerivedField>
</TransformationDictionary>
```

### Question

So how am I supposed to scale with orig/norm or compute min/max from these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. After carefully reading again through the [Documentation](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/Transformations.html) (which is extremly confusing imo) i came across this sentence:

> The sequence of LinearNorm elements defines a sequence of points for a stepwise linear interpolation function. The sequence must contain at least two elements. Within NormContinous the elements LinearNorm must be strictly sorted by ascending value of orig.

Which basically explains it all. Normalization in PMML is done by using a stepwise interpolation with only 2 points. So in fact just a simple conversion function.

In the case of normalization into a range of 0-1 it even get's easier as the **two points** will always be at `x1=0` and `x2=1` (orig values). And will therefore always have their y **axis intercept at orig=0 norm-value**. As far as the slope of the function is concerned it is also very easy to calculate by `slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (y2-y1)/(1-0) = y2-y1` which are just the 2 norm-values.

So to get our interpolation function which will always be a polynom 1st grade we just calculate:

`f(x) = ax + b = (y2-y1)x + y1 = (norm(orig=1)-norm(orig=0) * x + norm(orig=0)` This is used for **normalization**.

and now we can calculate the inverse:

`x = (f(x) - norm(orig=0)) / (norm(orig=1)-norm(orig=0))` This is used for **de-normalization**

Hope this helps everyone who at someday will also go through the hassle of implementing their own PMML executor engine and gets stuck at this topic.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm about to say depends on what you mean by `(min, max)`.

I'm going to assume that min equals the value where 0.5% of the total lies below and max equals the value where 0.5% of the total lies above.

If we agree on that, a symmetric normal distribution would have a mean value of approximately `mean ~ (max+min)/2`.  (You call the mean the origin.)

Six standard deviations encompasses 99% of a normal distribution, so the standard deviation is approximately `sigma ~ (max-min)/6`.

The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) of normalized `z = (x - mean)/sigma`.

With those values you can get yourself back to the denormalized distribution.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer but this really wasn't what i meant. I did try to re-formulate my question to make it clear what is meant by min,max and what my problem is.